# For loop causing issue on Angularjs app in a mean stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am having a strange problem where when i add a single line of code the app doesn't work after a refresh Here is my controller :

```
myApp.controller('messengernew', ['$scope', '$resource', 'AuthService', '$location', '$http', 'User','Message', function ($scope, $resource, AuthService, $location, $http, User, Message) {

$scope.users=[];
$scope.messages=[];


User.getAllUsers().then(function(users) {
    $scope.users = users;
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      (function(user){
        console.log('username ' + user.username);
        // User.incrementReputation(user.username);
        Message.getUnreadMessages(user.username, localStorage.getItem("token")).then(function(messages) {

            $scope.messages.push(messages);

        })
      })(users[i]);
    }
})


$scope.username=localStorage.getItem("token");

$scope.gotomessages = function (text) {

          var contact =text;
          localStorage.setItem("contact", contact);  
          $location.path('/messenger');
    };

}]);
```

If i uncomment `User.incrementReputation(user.username)`the app doesn't work after a refresh can you help ?

And the function incrementReputation is in a service and here is the code :

```
function incrementReputation(username) {

  getUser(username).then(function(users) {

      (function(user){

        $http.put('/api/incrementReputation', {}, {params:{id:user._id}});
      })(users[0]);

  })
}
```

and the function getUser also in a service (the same as incrementReputation ))
:

```
function getUser(username) {

           var Users = $resource('/api/users', {},{
           query: {method: 'get', isArray: true}
           });


         return Users.query({username:username}).$promise

          }
```

Comment: can you share code of function `User.incrementReputation(user.username)` and the error in console tab of develop tool if have ?

Comment: Do you see any error in the console ?

Comment: @Tan Le i updated my questioon suzo no error

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark with the given information. May be a semicolon issue in the getUser function.

```
return Users.query({username:username}).$promise;
```